# Behringer X 32 versus Midas M 32

Tags: behringer, console

What is the difference between the Behringer M 32 and the Midas R 32 consoles?

Comment: Type your title into google. There are hundreds of people comparing the two consoles with more detail than you’ll get on here

Comment: They don't answer my question!

Comment: do you have a more specific question about a specific feature that you want to know the difference of? Try to add that into the question.